# Put <a> Tag in <td> Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i must to put this  Tag

```
 <td><a id="<?php echo "pdf_file_".$id; ?>" style="color: black;" href="<?php echo $dateiinfo['dirname']."/".$dateiinfo['basename'];?>" ><?php echo $dateiinfo['filename']; ?> <br></a></td>
```

in a  Tag:

```
<td id="org"><br></td>
```

How can i make this?

i try it with that

```
org.appendChild( getElementById($id) );
org.removeChild( getElementById($id) );
```

Comment: You can add it using,
$('#org').html('<a></a>');

you can clear it using,
$('#org').html('');

Comment: `$("#org").append($("#pdf_file_" + id ));`  (refactor to get your $id in via php if needed)